# Проблема в cooldawn

Tags: c#, таймер

у меня возникла проблема, что даже при хорошо написанном коде(по моему мнению) у меня не работает кулдаун между телепортами. Есть ли какие либо советы?

```
    if (TeleportCDCurrent >= TeleportCD)
    {
        TeleportReady = true;
    }
    else
    {
        TeleportCDCurrent += Time.deltaTime;
        TeleportReady = false;
        TeleportCDCurrent = Mathf.Clamp(TeleportCDCurrent, 0.0f, TeleportCD);
    }
    
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X) && TeleportReady)
    {
         transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(1.50f, 0, 0);;
        TeleportCDCurrent = 0.0f;
    }
    
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X) && TeleportReady)
    {
         transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(-1.50f, 0, 0);
        TeleportCDCurrent = 0.0f;
    }
```

Comment: Что означает «не работает»?

Comment: Это вообще что? Unity?